# Regular expression matching linear-gradient

Tags: css, regex

Is it possible to get a correct split of a `background-image` linear gradient definition with a unique regex, ie :

```
linear-gradient(hsl(200, 83%, 64%), hsl(200, 81%, 59%) 32%, rgb(22, 22, 22) 81%, red)
```

What I'm looking for is to get multiple matches like this (in that case 4 matches):

```
$1:hsl(200, 83%, 64%)
$2:
$1:hsl(200, 81%, 59%)
$2:32%
$1:rgb(22, 22, 22)
$2:81%
$1:red
$2:
```

I'm currently trying something like :

```
(hsl\([^\)]*\))\s*(\d+%)?
```

But that only works for hsl, there must be some clever way to be less specific

Comment: What you want is to parse out all the hsl(xxx, xxx, xxx)s with corresponding %stop, but not the ones without %stop?

Comment: Nop I want them all, mainly the point is to get what is between the top-level commas, ideally splitting up between a color-string(hsl(), rgb(), #...) and the optional %-stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quote a number of formats for colour in CSS. Including

- `‹Name›` (eg. "red")
- `#rgb`
- #rrggbb
- `rgb(r, g, b)` (each number 0–255)
- `rgb(r%, g%, b%)`
- `hsl(...)` (as in the Q)

and then `hsla` and `rgba` which add an alpha channel. And finally the `currentColor` keyword.

Simplest approach would be to build a regex for each that you want to support, and then separate with alternation (`|`). To start with:

```
#[0-9a-fA-F]{3,6}|rgb ?\([ 0-9.%,]+?\)
```

which should cover the hex and (both) `rgb` forms. But it will also match invalid expressions (valid only will be more complex).

Finally, don't forget that `linear-gradient`:

- can start with a direction (eg. "to bottom") or angle
- each colour can include a stop (if you don't want the colours spread out evenly): either percent or distance
- there is also `repeating-linear-gradient`.